# Trying to run 'npm run build' got npm ERR! command failed npm ERR! command sh -c vue-cli-service build

Tags: node.js, npm, vuejs3

I am new to Vue. While learning from the tutorial (watch and code), I ran `$ npm run build` and I got this error. Using **vue3**

```
 ERROR  Error: CSS minification error: Parse error on line 1: 

^
Expecting "CALC", "LPAREN", "ADD", "SUB", "FUNCTION", "LENGTH", "ANGLE", "TIME", "FREQ", "RES", "UNKNOWN_DIMENSION", "EMS", "EXS", "CHS", "REMS", "VHS", "VWS", "VMINS", "VMAXS", "PERCENTAGE", "NUMBER", "expression", "math_expression", "function", "dimension", "number", got unexpected end of input. File: css/app.4b6f641c.css
Error: CSS minification error: Parse error on line 1: 

^
Expecting "CALC", "LPAREN", "ADD", "SUB", "FUNCTION", "LENGTH", "ANGLE", "TIME", "FREQ", "RES", "UNKNOWN_DIMENSION", "EMS", "EXS", "CHS", "REMS", "VHS", "VWS", "VMINS", "VMAXS", "PERCENTAGE", "NUMBER", "expression", "math_expression", "function", "dimension", "number", got unexpected end of input. File: css/app.4b6f641c.css
    at /home/benjamin/vue-crash-2022/node_modules/@intervolga/optimize-cssnano-plugin/index.js:106:21
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/benjamin/vue-crash-2022
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c vue-cli-service build

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/benjamin/.npm/_logs/2022-02-04T14_40_59_455Z-debug.log
```

I don't really have clue at all about this error and Vue. I will appreciate clarity in answers or recommended documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I caught the error. The errors were in my internal css. When I commented them, it worked perfectly.

If anyone has similar problem, just work through your internal css code, anywhere you have them, make sure they are all correct.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).